# How to sum under different sheet with conditions? Libreoffice calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a libre office calc spreedsheet containing over 10 sheets.

They have the same structures.

on the standard sheet there are multiple columns with start and end which people need to put their timestamp(C2 = 2015-04-21 02:28  and D2 = 2015-04-21 03:31)

I can calculate the time easily with this doing D2-C2

I need to create another sheet to sum all time that had been done within a day.

What I think of doing is :
-Add every cell within the range of sum(firstsheet.C2:lastsheet.C100) that has the same day (ex. 2015-04-21)
-Do the same with the D row
-Substract the 2 rows so I can only get the total time in hours for one day

Is there any way to do this without using macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll be better off putting all the data into **one sheet** and using a pivot table (or multiple pivot tables) to display the daily sums as well as whatever "report" type information you're currently displaying on each sheet.

Sometimes a pivot table is called a data pilot - they are the same thing.  For your application, they work the same in Excel as in LibreOffice, so if you're looking for information Excel tutorials are valid.  Here is also a tutorial on the OpenOffice wiki: [Using the DataPilot](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/DataPilot) - Please note the links to each part of the tutorial is through the table of contents on the right side of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link with some explanation [Libre Office help](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Applying_Multiple_Sheets)

I did not try it but maybe the sheets should have a name y with X incrementing by 1. So the format yX

Comment: That I can already do, just need to take the first sheet in the bottom  and last sheet as in firstsheetname.C2:lastsheetname.C100. My problem is more with the condition of the sum ( only add the day that are of the same day)